Extracting Item Dimensions from a Column
How would I extract the item dimensions/measurements stored as text from a column into a pre-existing column? The data I'm working with doesn't have much consistency in where the dimensional data is located within each column and how it's formatted.
Example:



Index
Item Description




1
Panel 96H


2
72W Couch


3
Table 18x36 Corner


4
18"x20" Ottoman


5
Table 24"


6
Seal 18'


7
Cubby 48"W * 16"D * 16"Hw/Drawers


8
82.7"W x 47/2"H x 0.4"D


9
Lounge 48"W



I would appreciate any help in trying to solve this problem; I'm currently at a loss for how to even approach this problem.
*Edit: In case text Table doesn't display correctly


Recognizing you've stated you don't know where to start, the tagging of powerquery would indicate some level of script generated to work through the activity (missing information from post, leading to subjective responses).   As your data is all over the place, some have multiple dimensions within the single string, I would have a hard time determining a way to pull sub-sections of the string consistently... possibly splitting each string and determining where the first character is numeric and working from that; it would still leave a lot of variability, which could be in the metadata

A perfect example of the difference between "data" and "information".  What you have is information and you're trying to extract data.  With the examples you provided, there's no way to 100% guarantee accurate data. Your dimension flags (W,H,D) are not unique within the text, so there's no way to identify if a "D" refers to Depth or Drawers.

Using regular expressions via Python (in PQ) is a good option. Here's a suggestion to give an idea, using REGEXEXTRACT Function - Microsoft Support available in Excel for Microsoft 365:
=MAP(B2:B10, LAMBDA(a, CONCAT( REGEXEXTRACT(a,
"\d+([./]\d+)?['""]?[WHD]?(\s*[x*]\s*)?",
1))))




Pattern
To match




\d+([./]\d+)?
number with optional decimal or fraction


['""]?
(optional) feet or inches (double up double quotes)


[WHD]?
(optional) W, H or D


(\s*[x*]\s*)?
(optional) x or * between





Power Query, using JavaScript (Windows only)
Here's a suggestion with PQ & JavaScript, not very efficient, but may be fine for your data:

using Web.Page to use regex match
create a blank query and enter in Advanced Editor
Adjust table/column names to match your data

let
  extractDims =
    let
      re = (str, regex) =>
        let
          html = "
  <script>
    var str = '" & str & "';
    var re = " & regex & ";
    document.write(str.match(re).join(''));
  </script>",
          res = Web.Page(html)[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}
        in
          res,
      Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
      regex = "/\d+([./]\d+)?['""]?[WHD]?(\s*[x*]\s*)?/g",
      res = List.Transform(Source[Item Description], each re(Text.Replace(_, "'", "\'"), regex))
    in
      res
in
  extractDims


